# Error: Connection activation failed: Failed to find a compatible device for this connection

Tags: linux, linux-networking, namespaces, network-namespace

Hi linux newbie here pardon any mistakes.

I have configured a network namespace *local-routeTable* and have brought up interface eth3 inside the namespace:

```
# ip netns exec local-routeTable ifconfig
eth3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet 10.2.32.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 10.2.47.255
        inet6 fe80::b3ff:fe12:84d7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:00:b3:12:84:d7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 503  bytes 64792 (63.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 283  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 152  bytes 30010 (29.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Everything good so far, but now I want to bringup a sub-interface eth3.1 in my root/default namespace:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth3.1
DEVICE=eth3.1
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.2.16.1
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
NETMASK=255.255.240.0
```

But hitting this issue consistently:

```
[root@wdc-10-206-223-62 tmp]# ifup eth3.1
WARN      : [ifup] You are using 'ifup' script provided by 'network-scripts', which are now deprecated.
WARN      : [ifup] 'network-scripts' will be removed in one of the next major releases of RHEL.
WARN      : [ifup] It is advised to switch to 'NetworkManager' instead - it provides 'ifup/ifdown' scripts as well.
Error: Connection activation failed: Failed to find a compatible device for this connection
```

Even if I try to bringup the subinterface within the namespace where the eth3 interface is up, it still fails with the same issue:

```
[root@wdc-10-206-223-62 tmp]# ip netns exec local-routeTable ifup eth3.1
WARN      : [ifup] You are using 'ifup' script provided by 'network-scripts', which are now deprecated.
WARN      : [ifup] 'network-scripts' will be removed in one of the next major releases of RHEL.
WARN      : [ifup] It is advised to switch to 'NetworkManager' instead - it provides 'ifup/ifdown' scripts as well.
Error: Connection activation failed: Failed to find a compatible device for this connection
```

Im new to namespaces, any pointers to resolve this as well to deep dive into namespaces will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your system up to date?

Comment: @MichaelHampton 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="8 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"

Comment: OK, it's CentOS 8, but is it up to date?

Comment: I just updated it @MichaelHampton and the issue persists.